# Cannot run java project after converting to Maven in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

After some hours of trying I give up. After converting my java project to maven in Eclipse, I can't seem to run the application via the main class.

Have changed source folder to src/main/java and added some changes to my pom file, but still dosen't work. What am I forgetting?

I'm totally new to Maven, but have read alot stack posts, but none seem to solve the issue.

**pom file:**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.NorthQStandAloneJava</groupId>
<artifactId>NorthQStandAloneJava</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
<description>
    Simple UI based program that can switch on a Qplug from NorthQ
</description>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.Controller.Main</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

</project>
```

[image: Project structure]

Have already done the following:

```
1 - Run install maven
2 - Run as java application and pointing to the main class in the Controller folder
```

Hope someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Why not file > new > maven project, get that running, then copy over all your files?

Comment: Your packaging should be jar, not pom. If your main class is `com.Controller.Main`why don't you have a `com` package right under src/main/java? And why don't you respect the package naming conventions (all lowercase)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must change:

`<packaging>pom</packaging>` to `<packaging>jar</packaging>`

and

`<mainClass>com.Controller.Main</mainClass>` to `<mainClass>Controller.Main</mainClass>`

Plus: remember java code conventions (packages must be lowercase)